# How to write a query in eloquent that is like parentheses in SQL?

Tags: php, postgresql, eloquent

I have a query where all parameters are optional I want to select rows in the following situation: "select all products that have a marketplace_id or account_id and have a title". Put it another way

```
 select * from produts where (marketplace_id in (...) or account_id in (...)) and title ilike "blah".
```

That is the farthest I could get.

```
   $query = Product::query();

    if($parametros_pesquisa['marketplaces'] !== null )
    {

       $query->whereIn('marketplace_id', $search_parameters['marketplaces']);

    }if($parametros_pesquisa['contas'] !== null){         

        $query->orWhereIn('conta_id', $search_parameters['account']);

    } if($search_parameters['titulo'] !== null){

        $query->where("titulo", 'ilike', '%' . $search_parameters['titulo'] . '%');


   }
```

Here, `$search_parameters['marketplaces']` and `$search_parameters['account']` will be an array of ids, [1, 2, 3]. I check if the user-specified the search criteria and include it dynamically in the query. It seems the query is executing like the parentheses in the query doesn't exist. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback into `where` to group `or`.

```php
//quick example of Parameter Grouping:

$query = Product::query();

$query->where(function ($query) use ($search_parameters){
     $query->whereIn('marketplace_id', $search_parameters['marketplaces'])->orWhereIn('conta_id', $search_parameters['account']);
})->where("titulo", 'ilike', '%' . $search_parameters['titulo'] . '%');
```

Please read DB Query Builder Laravel: [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

The answer showed the way. I was able to see if the parameters were passed and add the conditions dynamically.

```
 $query->where(function ($query) use ($parametros_pesquisa){

            if($parametros_pesquisa['marketplaces'] !== null && $parametros_pesquisa['accounts'] !== null){

                $query->whereIn('marketplace_id', json_decode( $parametros_pesquisa['marketplaces']))->orWhereIn('conta_id', json_decode( $parametros_pesquisa['accounts']));

            }elseif($parametros_pesquisa['marketplaces'] !== null){

                $query->whereIn('marketplace_id', json_decode( $parametros_pesquisa['marketplaces']));

            }elseif($parametros_pesquisa['accounts']  !== null){

                $query->whereIn('conta_id', json_decode( $parametros_pesquisa['accounts']));

            }

       });
```